# Query Expression not working after upgrading to Access M365

Tags: ms-access

Why would this query expression stop working after upgrading from Access 2016 to Access M365?

Query Expression is BeginTime:

```
IIf(IsNull([BeginTimeOff]),"",CDate(Left([BeginTimeOff],8))).
```

What it does - takes time in SQL, if null, returns blank.  If exists changes SQL time to long time.

Example - 13:30:00.0000000 changes to 1:30:00 PM (long time).

What changed in Access M365?  Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 'stoppeed working'? Your IIf looks weird, you have a conversion from date to string, cutting the result to 8 chars and converting back to a date. That will be converted back to a string. All those conversions depend on the current locale. If you want a locale independent formatting, try `Iif(IsNull(BeginTimeOff), "", Format(BeginTimeOff, "h\:nn\:ss AM/PM"))`. Have a look at the docs for the possible [format strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications#user-defined-datetime-formats).

Comment: Your formula working for me in `O365`. I think last dot `(.)` may cause problem.  Expression shouldn't have last dot. `IIf(IsNull([BeginTimeOff]),"",CDate(Left([BeginTimeOff],8)))`

Answer (score 2):

The value `13:30:00.0000000` indicates, that it is stored as *DateTime2*. By default, this is read in Access as *text*, thus your conversion is correct:

```vb
CDate(Left([BeginTimeOff],8))
```

However, using an empty string, `""`, as parameter in `IIf`, forces `IIf` always to return a string, thus your converted date will be casted to text using the default time format of your Windows.

So, to have either *Null* or a true date value returned, either use *Null* as the parameter:

```vb
IIf(IsNull([BeginTimeOff]),Null,CDate(Left([BeginTimeOff],8)))
```

or reduce the expression using the good old `CVDate` as this (and also `Left`) accepts *Null* values:

```vb
CVDate(Left([BeginTimeOff],8))
```

The resulting *DateTime* value (or *Null*), you can format as to your preferences.

For some limited support in Access for *DateTime2*, go to:

- *Settings, Current database, last setting in right pane,* and mark
- *Support date/time extended data type (DateTime2) for linked/imported tables*

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your answers!  All would have worked - and some of them were in my original code.  The issue wasn't the code - Access 2016 was 32 bit and Access M365 is 64 bit.  I figured this out after receiving another error. After some searching, found a way to work around the issue.